# Find two dates entered are between or overlap for a user

Tags: sql

I am entering two days and trying to find if the dates entered are between or overlap for a particular user.  I seem to be getting the wrong results for an EmployeeID that does not exist in the table.

Data that I have in the table

```
EmployeeID  LeaveStart              LeaveEnd
         1  2015-04-14 00:00:00.000 2015-04-14 00:00:00.000
         1  2015-05-01 00:00:00.000 2015-05-02 00:00:00.000
```

If I run this query I get the expected results as the dates between the range is already in the table for EmployeeID 1

```
SELECT EmployeeID,LeaveStart,LeaveEnd  from EmpLeaves where (LeaveStart >= '2015-04-30' and  LeaveStart<= '2015-05-04') or (LeaveEnd between '2015-04-30' and '2015-05-04')
    and employeeid=1 

1   2015-05-01 00:00:00.000 2015-05-02 00:00:00.000
```

If I run the same query for EmployeeID=2 which does not exist in the table I get the same result, seems to be on of the conditions is returning true and ignoring the rest, so I can put anything as the EmployeeID and I still get the same result.  Somewhere I am missing something.

```
SELECT EmployeeID,LeaveStart,LeaveEnd  from EmpLeaves where (LeaveStart >= '2015-04-30' and  LeaveStart<= '2015-05-04') or (LeaveEnd between '2015-04-30' and '2015-05-04')
    and employeeid=2

1   2015-05-01 00:00:00.000 2015-05-02 00:00:00.000
```

If I remove the or part in the LeaveEnd I get the expected result, but then I also need to find out if dates fall between the LeaveEnd field too

```
SELECT EmployeeID,LeaveStart,LeaveEnd  from EmpLeaves where (LeaveStart >= '2015-04-30' and  LeaveStart<= '2015-05-04') 
    and employeeid=2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your logic, you need to fix the parentheses in the `where` clause:

```
SELECT EmployeeID, LeaveStart, LeaveEnd
from EmpLeaves
where ((LeaveStart >= '2015-04-30' and  LeaveStart<= '2015-05-04') or
       (LeaveEnd between '2015-04-30' and '2015-05-04')
      ) and
      employeeid = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The sort answer is you are missing a parenthesis around the date. However, your goal can be achieved by this.

```
SELECT EmployeeID
     , LeaveStart
     , LeaveEnd  
  FROM EmpLeaves 
 WHERE (LeaveStart <= '2015-05-04'
   OR   LeaveEnd   >= '2015-04-30')
   AND EmployeeID  = 1
```

Comment: May not work as I need to find out if the date applied has any dates in table that fall between them